# SwiftUI - Navigation bar back button appears for a fraction of second

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I have looked into many solutions but none of them works. My app navigation flow is

1. ViewController (UIKit) - pushes to SwiftUI view
2. This SwiftUI view shows the back bar button for a fraction of seconds and then gets hidden.

Here is my code:

```
struct FirstSwiftUIView: View {

var body: some View {

  VStack {
    Text("First SwiftUi View")
    NavigationLink {
      SecondSwiftUIView()
    } label: {
      Text("Next View")
    }
  }
  .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
  .navigationBarTitle("")
}
```

}

Answer (score 13):

I have found the fix. The back button can be hidden from UIHostingController before coming to SwiftUI from UIKit.

```
let firstSwiftUI = UIHostingController(rootView: FirstSwiftUIView())
firstSwiftUI.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
navigationController?.pushViewController(firstSwiftUI, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this trick:

```
final class CommonHostingController<Content: View>: UIHostingController<Content> {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

Your navigation bar of SwiftUI view will show immediately, but navigation bar of your UIKit viewController will hide during push animation.

Looks better.

Answer (score 0):

- wrap the view in a `NavigationView`. (maybe you did this in the App strucutre)
- use the `.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)` in the destination view – because there you want to hide the back button.

  struct ContentView: View {

  ```
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("First SwiftUi View")
                NavigationLink {

                    // your destination view
                    Text("Destination")
                        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)

                } label: {
                    Text("Next View")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("")
        }
    }
  ```

  }

Comment: The view from which I am coming to FirstSwiftUIView is in UIKit (a ViewController) and it already has a UINavigationController. So adding NavigationView again in SwiftUI will create two navigation bar on the top.

Comment: then just delete my additional `NavigationView` – the important point is, that the `.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)` is on the inner view.

Comment: Actually this works fine if first and second view are SwiftUI. But not when I navigate from UIKit to SwiftUI.